# Are projective planes of order n unique up to an isomorphism?

Tags: combinatorics, projective-geometry

Title is the entire question: Are projective planes of order n unique up to an isomorphism?

If so is there a simple proof for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are non-Desarguesian planes of order $p^2$ with $p$ an odd prime,
for instance the [Hall plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_plane).

The classical projective planes defined by finite fields are Desarguesian.